# String column to Dtm(date time) column in R

Tags: r

How does one convert a column from str to dtm? I've tried as.date and strptime and non of those works. Say I have a table with a column with 3 attributes (2003/11/04 19:29, 2001/04/02 21:32, 2003/10/28 09:51) in the str format. How would I covert this column so that it is in the dtm format? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `?strptime` for different format arguments. You can do:

```
x <- c('2003/11/04 19:29', '2001/04/02 21:32', '2003/10/28 09:51')
as.POSIXct(x, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
#Can also be done with `strptime`
#strptime(x, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M", tz = "UTC")
#[1] "2003-11-04 19:29:00 UTC" "2001-04-02 21:32:00 UTC" "2003-10-28 09:51:00 UTC"
```

Or with `lubridate`

```
lubridate::ymd_hm(x)
```

Replace `x` with column name `df$column_name`.

Comment: The lubridate command worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the fast answer!